# How to create csv file and send it without saving it to a disc?

Tags: node.js

I know that I just can create a string of csv data and Stream it, but the receiver doesn't recognize its extension in this case.

This problem is easily solved, when I firstly save the String data to a files with .csv extension.

But is there any method to send a file and make the receiver to understand it's extension without saving to a disc?

Comment: What methods are you using for sending the file? If the file is recognized, then there must be some metadata (like the file name) so the other side is able to recognize the file. I think you should be able to send this metadata even when sending just the string.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with streaming files, but this sounds like a potential MIME type miscommunication. CSV's is `text/csv`, if I'm not mistaken.